# C# - SerialPort does not exist in the current context - System.IO.Ports

Tags: c#

My code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object portName in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine apart from the error:
The name 'SerialPort' does not exist in the current context

I don't understand because I have **using System.IO.Ports;**
.NET 6.0 Windows Forms C#

Answer (score 2):

In .NET core you will need to install the NuGet package `System.IO.Ports`.

[image]

You can do it via either the intellisense or in the NuGetPackageManager for your application

[image]

Make sure nuget.org is selected in the NuGet Package Manager

[image]

and make sure that your nuget.org source is `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` (in Visual Studio 2022, C# 6, as of Oct 2022)

[image]

If you had taken code from a sample based on .NET Framework, the reference is added by default and the `using` statement would be enough.

Comment: I tried that already. "No packages found" in Nuget Package manager when I search for : "System.IO.Ports"

Comment: Is your source nuget.org? Do you have any IT issue blocking access to the server?

Comment: Project -> Manage Nuget Packages -> Browse -> System.IO.Ports search has no results. Heres a picture: https://ibb.co/yd1bH61

Comment: Check your image, the `Package Source` to the right is `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`. Can you change it to `nuget.org`?

Comment: Like this? https://ibb.co/P13Z90N I'm getting an error. [Package source] The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsAbsoluteLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net6.0-windows7.0'&includePrerelease=true&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'system.security.cryptography.encoding' from source 'Package source'.
[Package source] The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/Search()?

Comment: I don't know. See my latest picture. nuget.org and the offline one are both available as options for me in the dropdown. If you can't select it from there then you have another issue

Comment: In my settings, the address is `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: That worked with that source. Thank you so much @djv